# How can I get all parents of an element?

Tags: php, mysql, hierarchy

I have a query (+php) for getting all childs of a parent but now flipping it over so I get all parents of an element would be more useful.

Table:

```
ID     parentID     showOrder
===============================
1      0            0
2      1            0
3      2            0
4      3            1
5      3            2
6      3            3
```

Code:

```
<?php
$structure = array();
$sql = "SELECT ID, parentID FROM table ORDER BY parentID ASC, showOrder ASC";
while ($row = fetch_row()) {
  $structure[$row['parentID']][] = $row['ID'];
}
```

Output:

```
0: [1], 1: [2], 2: [3], 3: [5,4,6]
```

Preferred Result:

```
0: [], 1: [0], 2: [1, 0], 3: [2, 1, 0],
4: [3, 2, 1, 0], 5: [3, 2, 1, 0], 6: [3, 2, 1, 0]
```

How can I do this?

Comment: You mean ancestors, not just parents I assume?

Answer (score 0):

You're falling in the hierarchical query domain.

Although Oracle provides a very convenient way to proceed (`CONNECT BY` clause), mysql doesn't.

Following this link http://explainextended.com/2009/03/17/hierarchical-queries-in-mysql/ will explain you how to reach your goal through pure mysql.

If you wish to do it only through php, you also could, but it somehow would be inefficient as the engines switchs (communication between php/mysql: calling a query, coming back to php, and so on) could become costly after many iterations.

rgds.

Answer (score 0):

If the parents are always in order, you can keep the array of ancestors like so:

```
// initialize as empty
$ancestors = array();
while ($row = fetch_row()) {
    $ancestors[$row['id']] = array($row['parentid'] => $row['parentid']);
    // if the parent exists
    if (isset($ancestors[$row['parentid']])) {
        // grow ancestors by parent's ancestors
        $ancestors[$row['id']] += $ancestors[$row['parentid']];
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 0
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [1] => 1
            [0] => 0
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [2] => 2
            [1] => 1
            [0] => 0
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [3] => 3
            [2] => 2
            [1] => 1
            [0] => 0
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [3] => 3
            [2] => 2
            [1] => 1
            [0] => 0
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [3] => 3
            [2] => 2
            [1] => 1
            [0] => 0
        )

)
```